# Decision Tree Depth?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree, pruning

I am trying to implement a Decision Tree model with depth equal 10. I am using the comand "max_depth=10" on the list of arguments (SciKitLearn), but when I print the max_depth of my model, the result is 34. My code follows:

```
AD5 = tree.DecisionTreeRegressor( max_depth=10) 

AD5 = AD.fit(X_train, Y_train) 

print(AD5.tree_.max_depth)
```

Does anyone how to fix it?

Comment: Check your code for typo, it was `AD.fit(X_train, Y_train)` instead of `AD5.fit(X_train, Y_train)`